# Setting tenant scope for DelayedJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant Rails app that has a `tenant_id` column on many models.

Each model that belongs to a specific tenant has a default scope based on a class variable on the Tenant class:

```
default_scope { where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_id) }
```

`Tenant.current_id` is set in the application controller.

The problem is that when I send mail (via a Delayed Job) regarding a tenant-scoped object (ie. `UserMailer.delay.contact_user(@some_user_in_a_specific_tenant)`), I get `NoMethodError`s for `nilClass` whenever I call anything on `@some_user_in_a_specific_tenant` within the Mailer. Presumably because the Delayed Job process isn't setting the `Tenant.current_id`.

How can I get DJ to access the objects I'm passing in?

Answer (score 1):

Grab the current_id when you queue the job and build a scope out of that that doesn't depend on a class variable from the app.  Or get a list of record ids to operate on first, passing that to DJ.

Examples:

```
def method_one(id)
  Whatever.where(:tenant_id => id).do_stuff
end

def method_two(ids)
  Whatever.find(ids).do_stuff
end

handle_asynchronously :method_one, :method_two

# then
method_one(Tenant.current_id)

# or
ids = Whatever.all.map(&:id)
method_two(ids)
```

Comment: I see. My delayed methods all mailer methods, which makes it less straightforward, but I'll try that general method.

Comment: Yeah it's really the only reasonable way.  The delayed_job process is simply another app, pulling database records and running jobs.  It has no way to know about the state of your main app unless you tell it.

Comment: That looks promising. I'll try :)

Comment: if the `Whatever` class uses the `default_scope`, shouldn't `method_one` be:
`Whatever.unscoped.where(:tenant_id => id).do_stuff`?